# Как изменить текст в inline кнопке? Python 3.8 . pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Здраствуйте, помогите начинающему, пожалуйста. Я использую pyTelegramBotAPI, так вот, как изменить текст именно на inline кнопке, я ответа так и не смог найти, или просто невнимательно читал, в общем, помогите пожалуйста :)

Comment: требуется изменить текст кнопки после нажатия на эту кнопку?

Comment: да, так и нужно, что бы при нажатии на кнопку , текст кнопки менялся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты не точно задал вопрос. Тут при нажатии **меняется inline кнопка** с белого на черный

```
import telebot 

bot = telebot.TeleBot("ТОКЕН")  
 
markup1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
markup1_item1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Белый', callback_data='white')
markup1.add(markup1_item1)
    
markup2 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
markup2_item1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Черный', callback_data='black')
markup2.add(markup2_item1)
    
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def default_test(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text = "Нажми", reply_markup = markup1) 

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'white':
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="Нажми", reply_markup=markup2)
        elif call.data == 'black':
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="Нажми", reply_markup=markup1)
            
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Все, спасибо вам, я понял как это делается)

Comment: Пожалуйста, тогда поставь на мой ответ галочку (Ответ помог) @dust

Comment: я тут новичок, не шарю, вроде нажал знак галочки, она стала зеленой, это она же?

Comment: Да, молодец. На ответах которые тебе помогли, ставь галочку